# Countable Dense Subsets under Isometric Isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that if $X$ and $Y$ are finite dimensional normed spaces then if $X$ has a countable dense subset then $Y$ does also using an isometric isomorphism.

I'm struggling to show that the image of the countable dense subset is dense in $Y$.

Any hints are appreciated greatly!

Comment: A finite dimensional normed space always has a countable dense subset; namely, the set of linear combinations of a basis with rational coefficients.

Comment: So is there a proof for that?

Comment: the comment of David Mitra is a proof

Comment: so is there a proof for showing that every normed space has a countable dense subset?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the isometric isomorphism $T:X\to Y$ instead of the fact that $\dim Y<\infty$, let $\varepsilon>0$ and $y\in Y$. Let $S\subset X$ be countable and dense. Then there exists an $s\in S$ such that $\|s-T^{-1}y\|_X<\varepsilon$, so $\|Ts-y\|_Y<\varepsilon$.